# nesting http post request in a get request

Tags: javascript, json

What I am trying to do is get the data from API endpoint and displaying them in the input fields of my form then capture the password from the input field and posting the whole json to my endpoint
I tried nesting the HTTP requests the get is working fine but the post portion of it is not working properly

Here's my code

```
const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/api/mqtt", true);
http.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        console.log(http.responseText);
        var respond = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
        console.log("respond is" + respond);
        document.getElementById('broker-address').value = respond.ip;
        document.getElementById('broker-port').value = respond.port;
        document.getElementById('client-id').value = respond.client_id;
        document.getElementById('username').value = respond.username;
        document.getElementById('topic-prefix').value = respond.prefix;
        var param = document.getElementById('password').value;

        http.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/api/mqtt");
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        var data = {    
            ip: respond.client_id,
            port: respond.port,
            client_id: respond.client_id,
            username: respond.username,
            password: param, // POST only
            prefix: respond.prefix
        };

        var json = JSON.stringify(data);
        http.send(json);
   }
}
http.send();
```

The error I am getting is

```
VM4287:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token O in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.http.onreadystatechange
```

my GET response looks like this

```
  {"ip":"arduinoClient",
"port":"1883",
"client_id":"arduinoClient",
"username":"user1",
"password":null,
"prefix":"gos-lan-test/fx4t/pwr/node/mr/mod-1/"}
```

What am I doing wrong here, any better ideas?
Thank you

Comment: Can you check in your developer tools in network tab if request is being sent?

Comment: Check if`http.responseText` is a JSON type

Comment: check your http.responseText, I think it returns invalid json string so cause the error.

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik it is! i mean the request is being sent

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik well http.responseText is not json type which is why i parse it to json and i am only dealing with the respond from then, is it supposed to be done another way ?

Comment: As its name hints, `http.responseText` is always _**text**_ type. [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is formally text too, but it should comply with the respective strict format. Your response obviously doesn't comply with it.

Comment: @hindmost if u r referring to the get response i edited the post to show  it, i think i does comply with the format unless i misunderstood your point ?

Comment: @hindmost i did :)

Comment: Perhaps the actual response differ from what you posted here. Anyway your problem looks like unreproducible.

Comment: @hindmost it is the actual response, yeah seems like it :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out that the issue is because the Get request runs twice, once to get the 1st get respond which is a parse-able text to JSON that i posted in the question, second time after the post request which returns a response of "OK", which a string that can't be parsed as a json object, which throws this error
the problem can be solved with a simple if condition to prevent parsing if respond is "OK" or separating the GET and POST requests